# Serve files from MongoDB with Flask framework

Tags: file, mongodb, flask

I am new in web development with python and flask and mongodb database. What I see is that everybody advises to use Apache to serve files because it's more efficient. But what if I store all my files in MongoDB using GridFS? In this case I do not serve my files by Apache anymore but directly by flask, is it the wrong thing to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in a spot where you need to use GridFS to store files, then you will have to use Flask to serve them.

However, if you don't have to use GridFS I would recommend against it, especially as a newbie to web development.  There will be a lot more guides to help you along when you get stuck.  After you have Flask figured out, you can add on GridFS.

Comment: actually I still wonder what to do, I have a web app that let the user upload pictures for their profile, storing files directly in mongoDb let file managements easier but can have the performance trade off...

Comment: I would store the images on disk and not in the database.